# Factory class vs Spring DI

Tags: java, spring, design-patterns, dependency-injection

As per my understanding both Factory class and  Spring DI follows the Dependency injection. I mean  in both the cases external entity is used to push the dependency. **Right?**
My question is which one i should go for  between factory classes and Spring DI when my intention is just to get the objects . Assume i don't want any other features like aop, dao support etc. Only purpose is to get the objects either from Factory class or Spring DI. Which one is preferable.

on some site  read this statement

DI loosely coupled and less intrusive in comparison to Factory classes

**But could not get how spring  DI loosely coupled and less intrusive than factory classes?**
in both the cases we have to insert some kind of get object code in our core program .

Comment: “Just to get the objects”? Really? No behavior to them? Then just do `new Object()`. (Tell us more about what is going on so that we can know how to make useful recommendations. And Spring uses the Factory pattern extensively, among others.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spring DI promotes loosely coupled code because the Spring container injects your dependencies based on configuration.  If you are injecting interface implementations, you don't have to change code to change which specific implementation gets injected, unless you consider your configuration code, which many do.

If you use a Factory to create configured objects that are used by the rest of your code, you are writing code to create the objects, configure them, etc.  If you want to change what the factory returns, you have to change actual code, which some would argue is a more *intrusive* change.

Typically Spring is used to configure how the various layers of your application are wired together.  X service takes such and such DAO implementations, for example.  That's application level organization.  Lets say you have a scenario where want to create a button for every row in a list -- in that case you could use a factory to create the buttons.  This scenario is based on a runtime situation where the GUI has different elements that you couldn't configure up front (because its based on the data), so DI makes less sense here.

EDIT - based on your comment questions, I think the primary point here is that you have to consider is that Spring is also an *Inversion of Control* container.  That means you don't program in which components in your application go where.  Without IoC, you might do something like

```
MyServiceImpl extends MyService {
    Dao1 = new Dao1Impl(); // you programmatically configure which components go in here
    Dao2 = new Dao2Impl();
    ....
}
```

instead you do something like

```
MyServiceImpl extends MyService {
    public Dao1;  // you haven't specified which components, only interfaces
    public Dao2;
    ....
}
```

In the second code sample, Spring (or whatever you use) will inject the appropriate DAO instances for you.  You have moved control of which components to use to  a higher level.  So IoC and DI go hand and hand, IoC *promotes* loose coupling because in your component definitions (i.e. interfaces) you only specify behavior.

In other words, IoC and DI are not necessary for loose coupling; you can have loose coupling with a Factory too

```
MyServiceImpl extends MyService {
    public dao1 
    public dao2;

    MyServiceImpl(){
       dao1 = DaoFactory.getDao1();
       ...
    }
    ....
}
```

here your service still only depends on DAO *definitions* and you use the factory to get implementations.  The caveat is that your service is now coupled to the factory.  You can make it more loose by passing a Factory into your constructor if you want....

Also, dont forget that Spring provides other useful functionalities, like its transaction management.  That's incredibly helpful, even though you said for your app you don't need it.

Comment: Thanks for reply.I have further queries on your explanation, Para1:-in spring if we want to change the interface implementation then we we have to make the change in configuration file but in case of factory classes we have to make change in factory class itself. Are you saying here Making change in config file is easier than factory class. But how does it make it more lossely coupled because in in both the cases we are making change in external component either config file or factory class.......

Comment: continued..Para2:-If you want to change what the factory returns, you have to change actual code.Hope you are saying factory class code here when you say actual code.But in case of spring di also we have to make change in config file.How come less intrusive than factory class? Para3:-Are you saying here for resolving runtime dependency we can't use spring DI rather we have to use factory classes. If yes it would answer my another query at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7221615/how-to-configure-the-cofiguration-file-in-spring-if-we-want-to-decide-at-run-timeot

Comment: @mohit 1).  You have to change the config *only* if you change the class name, or what arguments Spring needs to construct an instance 2)  "Changing what the factory returns" is the same as changing what class you want, so with Spring you would have to change the config 3)Im not saying that, you could very easily get an applicationContext and grab objects that way if you wanted, and then configure them.

Comment: Thanks a lot . Could you also help me regarding post at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7221615/how-to-configure-the-cofiguration-file-in-spring-if-we-want-to-decide-at-run-time. I  need in urgent need of this fundamental.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

> But could not get how spring DI loosely coupled and less intrusive
>   than factory classes? in both the cases we have to insert some kind of
>   get object code in our core program .

Spring makes it less intrusive because it uses reflection to automatically "inject/create" the dependencies. Thus your code does not need a reference to a the factory.

Spring is generally used for "Singleton-like" object creation. People generally use custom factories for transient throw away object creation (like request objects).
In fact often times you will make Spring create and inject your custom factories (ie factory of a factory).